# Heatmap tool/software representation ideas

Tags: heatmap

All, looking some recommendations on software and/or libraries to do the following 
I want to present a very visual (possible interactive) heatmap

The data I have is as follows

Number of employees 5000

Number of Managers these employees roll up under approximately 150

**Versus**

employee adoption of "standard rules"  this can be  1) not started 2 inprogress 3) completed

So i'm strugglying with whats available out there to represent such a dataset in a colour heat mat. (with the option of rolling up by manager heatmap). My first thought was excel but wondering how from a footprint perspective I get 4000 rows or colums to fit ultimately on a PPT slide even if a screen shot
Not looking a solution here more some guidance so i can go and investigate

Thanks

Comment: Can you code? If so which languages?